# Problems with Creating a File Using f = open(filename, 'w') In Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am having problems with creating a file using the built-in python creating file system. Whenever I try running the file, I get the following:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "(file name)"`

I have tried many solutions, although I do not know what is causing the problem.

```
from date time import date
today = date.today()
daty = str(today.strftime("%m/%d/%y"))

filename = (str(name) + "'s Expenses - " + daty + ".txt")

f = open(filename, 'w')
f.write(str(name) + "'s Expenses:" + '\n')
f.write("Date: " + daty + '\n')
f.write("" + '\n')
f.write("------------------------------------------------" + '\n')
f.write("Entry 1:" + '\n')
f.write("Cost - " + str(cost_one) + '\n')
f.write("Place - " + str(place_one) + '\n')
f.write("Time - " + str(time_one) + '\n')
f.write("Payment Type - " + str(payment_type_one) + '\n')
f.write("------------------------------------------------" + '\n')
f.write("Entry 2:" + '\n')
f.write("Cost - " + str(cost_two) + '\n')
f.write("Place - " + str(place_two) + '\n')
f.write("Time - " + str(time_two) + '\n')
f.write("Payment Type - " + str(payment_type_two) + '\n')
f.write("------------------------------------------------" + '\n')
f.write("Entry 3:" + '\n')
f.write("Cost - " + str(cost_three) + '\n')
f.write("Place - " + str(place_three) + '\n')
f.write("Time - " + str(time_three) + '\n')
f.write("Payment Type - " + str(payment_type_three) + '\n')
f.write("------------------------------------------------" + '\n')
f.close()
```

What I was expecting it to create was a file with the name as:

`[Person's Name]'s Expenses - [date of file creation].txt`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are creating a filename with slashes in it - which are going to be interpreted as directory separators.  Changing the slashes in your `strftime()` call to dashes or some other character would be one fix.